# Como fazer uma função SE no SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia.

Como faço uma função SE no SQL server?
Por exemplo, tenho dados numa coluna e quando for `= '1';'masculino';'feminino'`.

Pode me ajudar por gentileza?

Comment: A clásula `WHERE` serve ou precisa do 'if' mesmo?

Comment: [assim](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: entáo rlinhares, como eu faria isso no código?

Comment: select case WHEN a.genero = '1' then  'Masculino' else 'Feminino' end as genero from  tabela

Comment: Uma opção é a função IIF(), se a versão do SQL Server for 2012 ou mais recente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso, o ideal é você usar o [**CASE**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), já que o retorno depende da validação do dado de um campo específico:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN campo_genero = '1' THEN 'Masculino' ELSE 'Feminino' END
FROM nome_tabela
```

Comment: Perfeito rLinhares. Obrigado, abs.